# "It performs better under circumstance A than circumstance B" or "...than under circumstance B"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

In my essay, I need to write many phrases similar to "under A than under B", which appears to be a bit too verbose after a while due to the many *under*'s. I am wondering if it is grammatically incorrect to omit the "under" **after** "than" or informal to do so.

So,

> It performs better under circumstance A than circumstance B.

Or,

> ...than under circumstance B.

Comment: Technically, the first case is ambiguous and could be interpreted as meaning "It performs better under circumstance A than circumstance B performs under circumstance A.", and someone being "humorous" or pedantic might point that out.  But in normal speech, people typically don't bother including the second "under".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first suggestion IS gramatically correct, "It performs better under circumstance A than B. To add variety, you may also choose to say thing like, "When tested under circumstances A and B, A gave better results" or "...A performed at a higher level." Whatever works for your specific situation.